# Center UIStackView not centering view

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistackview

I have this

```
view.addSubview(myName)
        myName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImage.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        myName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        myName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [myValue1,myValue2])
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myName.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

Any idea why it looks like this? I want it to be centered vertically like Example Text, I've tried adding

```
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

but then it looks like this

[image]

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myName.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

This should center the stack view itself against the `myName` label

note that if you want stuff in stack view to align nicely you have to give it some proportional or fixed widths, and give your stackview a width.

**Update**

if you want space between labels, add an extra `UIView()` between them into the stack:

```
let spacer = UIView()
spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true
 let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [myValue1,spacer, myValue2])
```

Comment: How do I add space between the UiLabels? now they are together

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, I'm creating this  lazy var spaceBetween : UIView = {
        let space = UIView()
        space.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true
        return space
    }() but it says invalid character in source file

Comment: `it says invalid character in source file` a) on which line b) why are you doing it via lazy?

Comment: Because I have my Views like this, created as lazy and then using on other file

Comment: @StuartDTO creating views as `lazy` is a crazy idea. Lazy will initialize and set values on first access and then store them. if you add them to two different view hierarchies, the EXACT SAME instance of the view is assigned to both. If you want a factory to generate `many of the same looking` views, just turn it into a `func`. If you need to dynamically add and hide parts of the UI, and don't want to build the hierarachy ahead of time, just add a func to build those parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208675/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-zaitsman).